# How can I set default value for data binding in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have assigned the data for variable `playState` before fire Code A , but the Code A still get the following error information.

*method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter aEPlayState*

I think `playState` is a `LiveData`, the initial value is null, it maybe cause error before I assign the data to it.

How can I fix it?  is Code B right?

**Code  A**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <import type="androidx.lifecycle.LiveData" />
        <import type="info.dodata.voicerecorder.model.EPlayState" />
      
        <variable
            name="playState"
            type="LiveData&lt;EPlayState>" />
      
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_small"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_small"  
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/play_play"
                app:iamgeForPlayPause="@{playState}"
                
            />
     </LinearLayout>

</layout>


@BindingAdapter("app:iamgeForPlayPause")
fun imageForPlayPause(aImageButton: ImageButton, aEPlayState: EPlayState) {
    ...
}

enum class EPlayState {
    STOPPED,
    PLAYING,
    PAUSED
}
```

**Code B**

```
<variable
   name="playState"
   type="LiveData&lt;EPlayState>" 
   default="EPlayState.STOPPED"
/>
```

Comment: I think your code will not work . AFAIK variable does not have a default attribute. Why not just initialize Live data with `EPlayState.STOPPED` state . You have to initialize it anyway.

Comment: Thanks! But LiveData is lazy, maybe it null even if I have  initialized it.

Comment: Thanks! But LiveData is lazy, maybe it null even if I have  initialized it.

Comment: In that case you can use `app:iamgeForPlayPause="@{playState!=null?playState:EPlayState.STOPPED}"`.

Comment: why do you actually want to use a livedata there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a null-check when you assign the value

```
playState != null ? .. : ..
```

But also reconsider why you use a livedata there..
You could also just bind the state and set it within an observer.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are using MVP or MVVM architecture for your implementation. It is not good idea to have business logic manipulation on UI part of code in my opinion. The PlayState related manipulation need to be done on ViewModel or Presenter. So I suggest add this LiveData as attribute of the ViewModel/Presenter associated with your fragment, initialize it in init block of ViewModel/Presenter class. Inside your fragment, assuming name of xml for your fragment is example_layout.xml add following code inside OnCreateView function of fragment as follows :

```
LayoutExampleBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).also {
            it.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
            it.viewModel = <ViewModel>
            it.playState = <ViewModel>.playState
}.root
```

(Or bind Presenter instead of ViewModel if using MVP architecture)